# j_security_check не проходит

Tags: weblogic

в проекте делаю авторизацию через `JAAS`, `weblogic 10.3.6` версии
в настройке `weblogic` создал юзера дал права админа
в `weblogic.xml` прописал следующее

```
<container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>

    <security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>EAdmin</role-name>
        <principal-name>EAdmin</principal-name>
    </security-role-assignment>
```

а в `web.xml` прописал следующее

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Success</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>EAdmin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>EAdmin</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

захожу по созданному логину попадаю в `404`